# How truthful is the Russian allegation, that Turkey is buying oil from ISIS?

Tags: russian-federation, turkey, islamic-state

[Russia has alleged](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/12/02/us-mideast-crisis-russia-turkey-idUSKBN0TL19S20151202) that Turkey is buying crude oil from ISIS?

- How does one verify that allegation?
- Is there any proof provided by Russia for that allegation?
- Are there any open source investigations(map routes, photographs etc) to prove the same?

Comment: There are a few possible interpretations of this. Do you mean, a) is oil from ISIS-controlled areas being sold in Turkey? (answer: yes, almost certainly); b) are Turkish authorities allowing oil from ISIS-controlled areas to be sold in Turkey? (answer: very likely, but it's not 100% clear how high up this goes, whether it's endorsed from the top or just individual corrupt officials on the ground); or c) as Putin claims, is Turkey's government and Erdogan's family *actively promoting* trade in oil from ISIS-controlled areas? (not sure about this one, I'm not aware of any strong evidence yet)

Comment: @user568458 I did not interpret Putins claims as *actively promoting*, but rather has permitting and benefiting.

Comment: There's no way to know this at this time. This is something worthy of an international investigation, not a StackExchange question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is way too soon to have an objective and distant view of this recent super-mediatised event. This is politics SE, not news SE (if there is one).

Comment: I can't imagine that not a single drop of the black stuff doesn't make its way from ISIS control into Turkey.  We can assume highly organised middlemen and whether elements of the Turkish authorities look the other way or not is apparently debatable.  I think it's largely a matter of asking to what extent does Turkey knowingly purchase oil from ISIS?  How traceable is the supply chain etc?  Most of all, who actually purchases ISIS-controlled oil?

Comment: I disagree with @Bregalad. This is a simple, definable question, and substantial documentation has been published supporting a simple, definable answer. A U.N. investigation would investigate details like who is to blame, how to make it stop, what market forces or ideologies or political power plays contribute to it, etc . . . but political questions don't get much easier than this.

Comment: There is so little oil in the area that it could easily be a low level smuggling without involving ISIS or the Turkish authorities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although I like the answer from @user3765080, I think that this question requires a definitive answer and the answer should be **yes**. If we ask about Turkey, we mean all the people of Turkey whether they are criminals or not. And buying oil from a terrorist organization is obviously criminal.

[To whom does the Islamic State sell their oil?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4915/to-whom-does-the-islamic-state-sell-their-oil) Sep 23, 2014.

> Islamic State oil is being sold to organized criminals in Turkey. -- [John Woo](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/4619/john-woo)

Comment: It's not just some "criminals"; see [my answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/19938/7643) at the question you linked to.

Comment: The original source of the claim is behind a paywall, but I suspect they are overblowing the trade. There is little oil in the area and with the rudimental machinery they have they cannot produce enough to sustain a weapons trade.

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge, new & tangible information has not emerged since this question was previously answered, so I'll summarize.

### [To whom does the Islamic State sell their oil?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4915/to-whom-does-the-islamic-state-sell-their-oil) Sep 23, 2014.

> Islamic State oil is being sold to organized criminals in Turkey . . . It is an open question to what extent Turkey is deliberately allowing this to occur. -- [John Woo](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/4619/john-woo)

### [Is Turkey covertly supporting the Islamic State?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6065/is-turkey-covertly-supporting-the-islamic-state) - Oct 24, 2014.

> I can't say if they are supporting them but they have some common interest . . . * . . . To sum it up, no they are not sympathizer of the Islamic State. They are mostly neutral toward them. -- [Vincent](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/4551/vincent)

This skips four good paragraphs by [Vincent](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/4551/vincent), so for more information I recommend reading the entire answer.

### [Did Turkey take revenge of Russian attacks on ISIS by downing the plane?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9368/did-turkey-take-revenge-of-russian-attacks-on-isis-by-downing-the-plane) Nov 25, 2015

> Turkish businessmen struck lucrative deals with Isis oil smugglers, adding at least $10m (£6.6m) per week to the terror group’s coffers, and replacing the Syrian regime as its main client. Over the past two years several senior Isis members have told the Guardian that Turkey preferred to stay out of their way and rarely tackled them directly. -- [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/nov/24/vladimir-putin-turkey-isis-terrorists-warplane-analysis), quoted by [bytebuster](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/2984/bytebuster)

And the following paragraph was not quoted, but was in one of [bytebuster](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/2984/bytebuster)'s sources.

> Elaborate trade networks have also evolved, with oil being smuggled across borders in plastic jugs and transported by trucks and on donkeys into Iraq and Turkey. -- [NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/01/29/world/middleeast/rebels-in-syria-claim-control-of-resources.html?_r=0)

**IN SUMMARY: "It is an open question to what extent Turkey is deliberately allowing this to occur."**